# Checkin Without Merge in Visual Sourcesafe

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I've got a file managed by Visual Sourcesafe 2005 which I have edited.  I'd like to check in the file exactly as-is on my box, but VSS always merges it with the file in the repository, breaking my code.

I don't know what I expected to happen...

Is there any way to check the file in without merge shy of deleting the existing file from the repo and adding my copy back in?

I've looked for command line options to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do "Undo check out" for all files, keeping their local versions on your machine; then again check out this files without getting latest versions from Visual SourceSafe; then check in all of them. In this case history is preserved. You just overwrite latest versions of files without any merge. Seems for me it's what you wanted.

I had the same problem and sorted it out in that way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting this answer here, but still really hoping that a better one comes up.

I figured that I can go into the VSS GUI and rename the file to ".old", then add my local file into the repo.  It's extremely hacky, but allows me to keep the file history.

Answer (score 1):

Such issue might happen when the file was checked out by multple people and there was a newer version checked in by others after your checkout. (See **Four scenarios that merge may be performed** #2 of [the article](http://www.kevingao.net/version-control/sourcesafe/file-merge.html) for more details.)

I don't see a option in SourceSafe CheckIn command to control that either. If you don't want merge happen, you may exclusively check out the file before editing.